# the value of binding annotations

Tags: guice

The typical example of using binding annotation is :-

```
public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {
    @Inject
    public RealBillingService(@PayPal CreditCardProcessor processor,
       TransactionLog transactionLog) {
         ...
}
```

I'd like to understand the value of the annotation, 'cause I can't create another constructor with another binding

```
public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {
    @Inject
    public RealBillingService(@BankABC CreditCardProcessor processor,
       TransactionLog transactionLog) {
         ...
}
```

it looks superfluous in the defining example, so I must be missing something.

I could do

```
public class BankBillingService implements BillingService {
    @Inject
    public BankBillingService(@Bank CreditCardProcessor processor,
       TransactionLog transactionLog) {
         ...
}
```

but then I'd still have to bind both (or more) classes

```
bind(CreditCardProcessor.class)
    .annotatedWith(PayPal.class)
    .to(PayPalCreditCardProcessor.class);

bind(CreditCardProcessor.class)
    .annotatedWith(Bank.class)
    .to(BankCreditCardProcessor.class);
```

and have a bunch of if this do that, kind of negating the value (by my understanding) of Guice.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? What do you want to achieve? Please edit the question with that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal for binding annotations is to *distinguish two different injection keys for the same class or type*. In your quoted example:

```
public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {
    @Inject
    public RealBillingService(@PayPal CreditCardProcessor processor,
       TransactionLog transactionLog) {
         ...
}
```

You might provide an alternative implementation:

```
public class StripeBillingService implements BillingService {
    @Inject
    public RealBillingService(@Stripe CreditCardProcessor processor,
       TransactionLog transactionLog) {
         ...
}
```

Or operate at an even higher degree of abstraction:

```
public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {
    @Inject
    public RealBillingService(@International CreditCardProcessor processor,
       TransactionLog transactionLog) {
         ...
}
```

One could also inject multiple arguments of similar types:

```
@Inject
public RealOrderRepository(
    @Customer DataStore customerDataStore,
    @Order DataStore orderDataStore,
    @Item DataStore itemDataStore) { /* ... */ }
```

As an alternative to this, which creates multiple unnecessary types in the hierarchy and makes it harder or impossible to create and replace generic implementations:

```
// Ideally you should have implementations like InMemoryDataStore and AwsDataStore;
// the below would force InMemoryCustomerDataStore or LocalDbItemDataStore
// regardless of whether you need them or not.

public interface CustomerDataStore extends DataStore { /* empty */ }
public interface OrderDataStore extends DataStore { /* empty */ }
public interface ItemDataStore extends DataStore { /* empty */ }

@Inject
public RealOrderRepository(
    CustomerDataStore customerDataStore,
    OrderDataStore orderDataStore,
    ItemDataStore itemDataStore) { /* ... */ }
```

Ultimately, your use of binding annotations should be *pretty rare*, only to distinguish different injection requests that would otherwise be the same type. In your example, if you wouldn't need `@Bank CreditCardProcessor` and `@PayPal CreditCardProcessor` at the same time in the same application, you could just bind `CreditCardProcessor` once and be done with it. However, if they might coexist, then you could bind them to the same credit card processor, or different card processors, or however it may need to change.

See also: [Guice's BindingAnnotations docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) and [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)'s [@Qualifier annotation docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html)